# dispatch_after is not calling after delay in iPhone device

Tags: ios, objective-c

This code is working fine at simulator but not at device.

Scenario is that after running code I move app to background mode then after 60 sec delay NSLog is calling in dispatch_after on simulator but at device it is not calling.

```
NSString *date = [self getStringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
const char *dateCharArray = [date UTF8String];
dispatch_queue_t myBackgroundQ = dispatch_queue_create(dateCharArray, NULL);
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 60 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delay, myBackgroundQ, ^(void){

    NSLog(@"%s", dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL));
});
```

Please someone help.

Comment: Once yoru app is suspended timer and `dispatch_after` do not fire until your app returns to the foreground.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any alternative way that I want to run some code after some time (more than 10 min or 1 hour) when app is in background/kill mode? If yes, please suggest.

Comment: No, there is no time-based background execution mode for iOS apps. You can use background fetch mode but this does not allow you to specify a particular execution time interval.